# ZF2 - How to render phtml file in triggered event?

Tags: zend-framework2

I need to render a phtml file in triggered event.

my code is :

```
class Module
{
//...
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
        $app = $e->getApplication ();
        $sem = $app->getEventManager ()->getSharedManager ();   
        $sem->attach ( 'Events', 'onExampleEvent', function ($e) {
            return 'html...';
        } );
    }
//...
}
```

how i can replace `html...` with rendered phtml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render your phtml file you have to follow some few steps:

1. Create a ViewModel object wich can hold your variables containers. If you need some variables just pass them as an array.

   ```
   $content = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel(array('article' => $article));
   ```
2. Specify the template to use with setTemplate.
3. Use the ViewRenderer to merge the ViewModel data with the appropriate template and return the rendred html.

The edited code below will fit your needs

```
class Module
{
//...
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
        $app = $e->getApplication ();

        $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

        $sem = $app->getEventManager ()->getSharedManager ();   
        $sem->attach ( 'Events', 'onExampleEvent', function ($e) {

            $content = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
            $content->setTemplate('your/template.phtml');  

            return $sm->get('ViewRenderer')->render($content);                                           

        });
    }
//...
}
```

Doc : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html